# How to remove border from header background

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, responsive-images

Today I tried to make a scroll web-site and at the first load I tried to make visible a header without nothing but with a css background. The background is responsive but I don't know why it doesn't cover all the screen and it has border or margin or padding, I don't know.

This is the simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleIndex.css">
</head>
<body>
<header id="logoSection">
</header>
<main>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the simple css:

```
header{
    margin: 0; //useless
    background-image: url("../asset/logoMovie.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

This is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXMKq.jpg)

I need a suggestion. Thx.

Like I described before I tried to make it full screen in the first part of the page, after the reader there will be other section, but the first it must be full screen.

Comment: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }` - this is your start point

Answer (score 1):

It's not a border what you see.

It's default `8px` `margin` of `body` element.

You can fix this issue by a simple reset.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I also suggest you to look for `box-sizing: border-box` property. It will definitely help you for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen because of the preset browser style, that means that all browsers have some default styles that they apply for all web aplications.
You can solve this problem applying a reset css to your html. Get it here:
[https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/][CSS Tools: Reset CSS]